# Is the curl of every non-conservative vector field nonzero at some point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Counterexamples? Intuitively, why?

Thanks for any answers.

As a side note, in what math class are gradient, divergence and curl taught typically?

Comment: Here's a nice counterexample from wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field. See the section on "Irrotational vector fields." These concepts are typically introduced in a standard multivariable vector calculus class.

Comment: Only if the domain is simply connected.

Comment: I learned gradient in multivariable calculus class, but didn't learn divergence and curl until vector calculus.

Comment: Suggestion: question body should not be treated as mere continuation of the title, they should be readable on their own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question to ask is:

> If there is a smooth vector field $\mathbf{v}$ such that 
>   $$\nabla \times \mathbf{v} = 0 \quad \text{ in } \Omega,$$
>   is there a smooth function $\phi$ such that 
>   $$\mathbf{v} = \nabla\phi?$$

- If the domain is [simply-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) (for example, a sphere, a box, but not cup with a handle), then this field must be a conservative field, i.e., $\mathbf{v} = \nabla \phi$.
- In general, we can have non-conservative field having zero curl. Let 
  $$Z = \mathrm{ker}(\nabla\times) := \{\mathbf{w} \text{ is smooth}: \nabla \times \mathbf{w} = 0\},$$ 
  which is the space of the fields having zero curl and 
  $$B = \mathrm{im}(\nabla) = \{\nabla \psi: \psi \text{ is smooth}\},$$
  which is the range of the gradient operator (i.e., all gradient fields). Then 
  $$
  \mathrm{dim}\big(Z/B\big) = \beta_1\tag{1}
  $$
  where $\beta_1$ is the [first Betti number](http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Betti_numbers) of the domain of interest $\Omega$, and 
  $$\beta_1 = (\# \text{ of holes in the domain})$$
  roughly speaking. (1) essentially means:
  $$
  \text{Field whose curl is zero} = \text{Conservative vector field } + \text{"Something"}. \tag{2}
  $$
  This "something" here is a $\beta_1$-dimensional space.
- (1) is the by the coincidence of the dimension of the de Rham cohomology group and homology group. For simply connected domain $\beta_1 =0$. If the domain has $k$ holes, the difference is a $k$-dimensional space.
- Intuition: To be honest I don't know the intuition here either, if someone knows please enlighten me as well.
- How to find this "something": Let's use that example in the [wiki's entry of conservative fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) AWertheim mentioned in the first comment, but modify it a little bit. For an infinite cylinder $C_{x=y=0,z\in (-\infty,\infty)}(1)$ with radius 1 in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that contains the origin, we dig a hole of radius $\epsilon$ along $z$-axis: 
  $$\Omega = C_{x=y=0,z\in (-\infty,\infty)}(1)\backslash  C_{x=y=0,z\in (-\infty,\infty)}(\epsilon)$$
  Then by above, that "something" is a dimension 1 space. Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a member of this something, we can pose a boundary value problem which is the technique used in Helmholtz decomposition of vector fields:
  $$\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  \nabla \times \mathbf{A} &= 0\quad \text{ in }\Omega
  \\
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} &= 0 \quad \text{ in }\Omega
  \\
  \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{\gamma_C} \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{s} &= 1 
  \\
  \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{n} &= 0 \quad \text{ on }\Gamma,
  \end{aligned}
  \right.$$
  where $\gamma_C $ is a counterclockwise closed curve lived on that interior cylinder surface with winding number 1, and $\Gamma$ is the boundary of the exterior cylinder. We can find that this $\mathbf{A}$ is what wikipedia's entry has:
  $$
  \mathbf{A} = \left( \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, 0 \right).
  $$
  That "something" in (2) is just a multiple of $\mathbf{A}$. And now we can say that if $\nabla \times \mathbf{v} = 0$ in $\Omega$ above, then
  $$
   \mathbf{v} = \nabla \phi + c\mathbf{A},
  $$
  where $c$ is a constant.
- Relevant question: [What is the solution to Nash's problem presented in "A Beautiful Mind"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284788/what-is-the-solution-to-nashs-problem-presented-in-a-beautiful-mind)
- Your last question: You can learn div, curl, and grad in Calculus III I believe. Like Green theorem, Divergence theorem, and Stokes theorem.

Comment: I don't know where my statement falls short, anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: Although I'm not the one who gave the downvote, I think it may have to do with presentation and also it would be nice if you expanded upon what you've said a little. Perhaps link to a page containing definitions or provide derivations of your own.

Comment: @user79365 Thanks, this makes sense, my bad.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId Thanks for the kind suggestion.